# K-means clustering MNIST dataset

Tags: python, mnist

I am currently working on the MNIST dataset and my training set is 60,000. This is coded in Python, and the task is asking me to perform clustering of the 6000 training vectors for each class into 64 clusters.

I was wondering how can I do that? Not sure how I do that with the KmeanCluster function from sklearn.

How do I split each class from the numbers 0-9 into 6000 training vectors?

Comment: You don't need the labels for kmeans. When you have the 64 clusters, there may or may not be an easy way to translate to numbers.

Comment: can you please elaborate more? thanks

Comment: kmeans attempts to find 64 clusters in your data. Thus, it will group each point in to 1 of 64 classes and that is just based on the pixel values, not on the label. There is no straightforward way of saying what the 64 clusters will mean. Thus, perform k means and see what clusters you get